# grouping checkboxes and allow checking a maximum of three in each group

Tags: jquery, html, forms, checkbox

I would like to have an application where a user will enter data for arbitrary individuals. each individual will have a choice of a maximum of three of six options. I want help on how to force a maximum of three choices using jquery on any indivual.

here is a sample code

```
<div id="subscriber_1">
   <input type=checkbox name=national>
   <input type=checkbox name=international>
   <input type=checkbox name=business>
   <input type=checkbox name=entertainment>
   <input type=checkbox name=religion>
   <input type=checkbox name=sports>
</div>
```

the subscribers can run upto 20, like subscriber_1, subscriber_2, ... subscriber_20. I will be grateful for your assistance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should add a class to your subscriber divs, to make it easier to attach event handlers:

```
<div id="subscriber_1" class="subscriber">...</div>
<div id="subscriber_2" class="subscriber">...</div>
```

And use this jQuery:

```
$('.subscriber :checkbox').change(function () {
    var $cs = $(this).closest('.subscriber').find(':checkbox:checked');
    if ($cs.length > 3) {
        this.checked = false;
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/frhpP/)

Explanation: On the change event of these checkboxes, we look for the closest parent that has the class `.subscriber`. We get the checked checkboxes inside this div. If there are more than 3 (the currently checked one counts as well), we uncheck the current one.

---

If you certainly don't want to add classes, you can use this selector instead:

```
$('[id^="subscriber_"] :checkbox')...
```

This is called the [Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

Comment: +1; from a ui perspective i'd also suggest having the handler show a message (non-modal) that says something like 'You are only allowed to check 3 boxes!'...

Comment: Ok, I have tried that. I have put the javascript in a file called control.js and added it in the header tag. I have tried it several times but the selection is limitless. whats wrong with my code or structure

Comment: @Tamseyc Have you put it in `document.ready()`? Have you added the class I suggested?

Comment: @bazmegakapa Yes I have done that. each div is in a different <tr> and each checkbox in a different <td>.

Comment: @Tamseyc Does not sound like valid HTML to me. Why don't you just add the class and id on the `tr`s then, and get rid of the `div`s?

Comment: @bazmegakapa I have a table. each tr of the table represents a subscriber. the subscriber has a name and phone number(textfields). All these are inside a tr including the six checkboxes. This means each tr has eight tds. In a nutshell this is the structure of the html. I have tried that but no joy still.

Comment: @Tamseyc OK, if you can't give me an URL where I can see your stuff live, please create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of your situation. That way, I could see what might be the problem. The code itself should work as demonstrated in my jsFiddle.

Comment: @Tamseyc On the left, I have selected jQuery to be included, and now it works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/7qwAE/5/

Comment: @bazmegakapa. wait a minute why is it that the same code works for you AND not for me. view at http://jsfiddle.net/7qwAE/7/

Comment: @Tamseyc In your fiddle, you have MooTools selected on the left. Select jQuery and it will work.

Comment: @bazmegakapa. Back to my actual code, nothing happens. I am stranded

Comment: @Tamseyc Well the problem is certainly not with my code, because our Fiddles show that it works. There must be something in your actual code. You could open a new question, paste your actual code there, or share it somehow. Or just debug :). Whichever, you could accept my answer here by clicking the tickmark on its left.

Comment: @bazmegakapa. I have debugged and located the problem within my code. Thanks for your useful assistance. My code works!!!!!! huh!!!!!!!

Comment: @kapa I tried with different ids for my divs, but they all get the same length, but I got different functions with different lengths.

Comment: I figured out that the limit variable needs to be inside the function. add inside the function `var limit = x`, where x is the number of how many can be checked.