# How to limit the number of selected checkboxes?

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox

I have the following HTML:

```html
<div class="pricing-levels-3">
   <p><strong>Which level would you like? (Select 3 Levels)</strong></p>
   <input class="single-checkbox"type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 1<br>
   <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 2<br>
   <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 3<br>
   <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 4<br>
   <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 5<br>
   <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 6<br>
   <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 7<br>
</div>
```

Live site:

http://www.chineselearnonline.com/amember/signup20.php

How can I do it so that the user can only select 3 of those checkboxes?

Comment: Already answered here: [grouping checkboxes and allow checking a maximum of three in each group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303443/grouping-checkboxes-and-allow-checking-a-maximum-of-three-in-each-group)

Comment: Protip: use <label> elements around your input and text to make them easier to click.

Comment: Similar questions have been answered already: - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337625/limit-number-of-checkboxes-to-be-selected-jquery - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463238/limit-number-of-checkboxes-allowed-to-be-checked Also:
https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+limit+number+checkboxes+selected

Comment: As a proof of concept I've achieved this with CSS only: https://codepen.io/fcalderan/full/dyoYePL

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Using `change` event you can do something like this:

```
var limit = 3;
$('input.single-checkbox').on('change', function(evt) {
   if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
       this.checked = false;
   }
});
```

[**See this working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vVxM2/)

Comment: I'd change `$(this).siblings(':checked').length`  to `$("input[name='vehicle']:checked").length;` for a more generic answer.  Yours only works if checkboxes share the same parent element.  This may not be the case if they are in different `<li>` or `<td>` tags.

Comment: @RickSmith agreed, but then you will also need to change `>= limit` to `> limit`, because you are now also counting the one that was just clicked.

Comment: Nothing happened. Still the same result. I can check how many I want even if I have `limit = 2`

Comment: This si doable if you dont have any styling, and literaly stack every checkbox next to each others. what if the inputs are no siblings

Answer (score 50):

Try like this.

On change event,

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function (e) {
    if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 3) {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
        alert("allowed only 3");
    }
});
```

Check this in [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ANNF9/)

Comment: this is the best solution in case of one list of checkbox in one page, thanks for the amazing answer :)

Comment: I prefer this answer, because it doesn't limit the checkboxes to being inside of labels or divs.

Answer (score 6):

Try this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jquerybyexample/SQdNQ/):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $("input[name='vehicle']").change(function () {
      var maxAllowed = 3;
      var cnt = $("input[name='vehicle']:checked").length;
      if (cnt > maxAllowed) 
      {
         $(this).prop("checked", "");
         alert('Select maximum ' + maxAllowed + ' Levels!');
     }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.checkbox').click(function(){
  if ($('.checkbox:checked').length >= 3) {
    $(".checkbox").not(":checked").attr("disabled",true);
  }
  else 
    $(".checkbox").not(":checked").removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

i used this.

Comment: I think it's much more simple and user friendly them above solutions

Answer (score 3):

I think we should use `click` instead `change`

Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Hammad_Hassan/zy7yc5bn/2/)**

Comment: Then there is a problem with a label binding. Change event is better, I think.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function(){
    if ($("input:checkbox:checked").length > 3){
      return false;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

### Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/m5EuS/680/)**

Try this

```
var theCheckboxes = $(".pricing-levels-3 input[type='checkbox']");
theCheckboxes.click(function()
{
    if (theCheckboxes.filter(":checked").length > 3)
        $(this).removeAttr("checked");
});
```

Comment: I had to add the limit inside the function: `var limit = x`, where x is the number of checked. Also this didn't work so I used https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303443/grouping-checkboxes-and-allow-checking-a-maximum-of-three-in-each-group but modified.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say like letiagoalves said, but you might have more than one checkbox question in your form, so I'd recommend to do like this:

```
  var limit = 3;
    $('input.single-checkbox').on('change', function(evt) {
        if($('input.single-checkbox').siblings('input.single-checkbox:checked').length > limit) {
            this.checked = false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("change", ".pricing-levels-3 input", function () {
      var numberOfChecked = $(".pricing-levels-3 input:checkbox:checked").length;
      if (numberOfChecked >= 2) {
        $(".pricing-levels-3 input:not(:checked)").prop("disabled", true);
      } else {
        $(".pricing-levels-3 input:not(:checked)").removeAttr("disabled", true);
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Is this answer different from others in this post or improves something?

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me with checkbox name.

```
<script>
    // limit checkbox select
    $('input[name=vehicle]').on('change', function (e) {
    if ($('input[name=vehicle]:checked').length > 3) {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
        alert("allowed only 3");
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I made it work:

```
// Function to check and disable checkbox
function limit_checked( element, size ) {
  var bol = $( element + ':checked').length >= size;
  $(element).not(':checked').attr('disabled',bol);
}

// List of checkbox groups to check
var check_elements = [
  { id: '.group1 input[type=checkbox]', size: 2 },
  { id: '.group2 input[type=checkbox]', size: 3 },
];

// Run function for each group in list
$(check_elements).each( function(index, element) {
  // Limit checked on window load
  $(window).load( function() {
    limit_checked( element.id, element.size );
  })

  // Limit checked on click
  $(element.id).click(function() {
    limit_checked( element.id, element.size );
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have Alter this function to auto uncheck previous

```js
      var limit = 3;
      $('.compare_items').on('click', function(evt) {
        index = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').index();
        if ($('.compare_items:checked').length >= limit) {
          $('.compare_items').eq(localStorage.getItem('last-checked-item')).removeAttr('checked');
          //this.checked = false;
        }
        localStorage.setItem('last-checked-item', index);
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="compare_items">1
<input type="checkbox" class="compare_items">2
<input type="checkbox" class="compare_items">3
<input type="checkbox" class="compare_items">4
<input type="checkbox" class="compare_items">5
<input type="checkbox" class="compare_items">6
<input type="checkbox" class="compare_items">7
<input type="checkbox" class="compare_items">8
<input type="checkbox" class="compare_items">9
<input type="checkbox" class="compare_items">10
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this today, the difference being I wanted to uncheck the oldest checkbox instead of stopping the user from checking a new one:

```
    let maxCheckedArray = [];
    let assessmentOptions = jQuery('.checkbox-fields').find('input[type="checkbox"]');
    assessmentOptions.on('change', function() {
        let checked = jQuery(this).prop('checked');
        if(checked) {
            maxCheckedArray.push(jQuery(this));
        }
        if(maxCheckedArray.length >= 3) {
            let old_item = maxCheckedArray.shift();
            old_item.prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This method works well with checkboxes in a container, such as bootstrap checkbox

```
    const checkedLimmit = 2;

    function ValidateCheckBoxGroup(container) {

        if (container.find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length >= checkedLimmit) {
            container.find('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', true);
            container.find('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').closest('div.checkbox').addClass('disabled');
        } else {
            container.find('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', false);
            container.find('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').closest('div.checkbox').removeClass('disabled');
        }
    }

    $(function () {
        // validate containers on page load
        $('div.checkbox-group').each(function () {
            ValidateCheckBoxGroup($(this));
        });

        // set checkbox events
        $('div.checkbox-group input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
            ValidateCheckBoxGroup($(this).closest("div.checkbox-group"));
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**JS and HTML**
This worked for me what it does is that, the onclick  function `checkControl()` will count the number of times the checkbox has been clicked then if it's greater than 3 display error message.

```js
 function checkboxControl(j) {
            var total = 0;
            var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox");
            var error = document.getElementById("error");
            for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
                if (elem[i].checked == true) {
                    total = total + 1;
                }
                if (total > 3) {
                    error.textContent = "You Must Select at Least 3";
                    elem[j].checked = false;
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="">
          <span id="error" style="color: red"></span>
          <br>
           <span>Python</span>
            <input
                type="checkbox"
                class="checkbox"
                name="interest[]"
                onclick="checkboxControl(0)"
                id="1"
            />
            <br>
            <span>Javascript</span>
            <input
                type="checkbox"
                class="checkbox"
                name="interest[]"
                onclick="checkboxControl(1)"
                id="1"
            /><br>
            <span>Go</span>
            <input
                type="checkbox"
                class="checkbox"
                name="interest[]"
                onclick="checkboxControl(2)"
                id="1"
            /><br>
            <span>Laravel</span>
            <input
                type="checkbox"
                class="checkbox"
                name="interest[]"
                onclick="checkboxControl(3)"
                id="1"
            />
          
        </form>

       
    </body>
</html>
```

**This resources helped me understand
https://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/checkbox-limit-demo2.php**

Answer (score -1):

If you want to uncheck the checkbox that you have selected first under the condition of 3 checkboxes allowed. With vanilla javascript; you need to assign onclick = "checking(this)" in your html input checkbox

```
var queue = [];
function checking(id){
   queue.push(id)
   if (queue.length===3){
    queue[0].checked = false
    queue.shift()
   }
}
```

Comment: I think this can be improved further by checking if a checkbox is unclicked, and removing it from the list if it is.

Answer (score -1):

This function simply checks if you have just checked a checkbox. If yes, it increments the `checked` value by one. If it reaches the limit then the next checkbox is rejected.

```js
var limit = 3;
var checked = 0;
$('.single-checkbox').on('change', function() {
  if($(this).is(':checked'))
    checked = checked+1;

  if($(this).is(':checked') == false)
    checked = checked-1;

  if(checked > limit) {
    this.checked = false;
    checked = limit;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pricing-levels-3">
  <p><strong>Which level would you like? (Select 3 Levels)</strong></p>
  <input class="single-checkbox"type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 1<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 2<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 3<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 4<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 5<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 6<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 7<br>
</div>
```