# Limit number checkbox checked JQM

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, checkbox, limit, checked

I tried all the methods present on this topic to block the number of checkbox checked, but to no avail it does not work with the form of JQM. 
I also change the solutions to try with name and onclick on element

It does not detect any reaction

[Solution Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001844/how-to-limit-the-number-of-selected-checkboxes)

Comment: `input` has no _siblings_ as jQM wraps `input` in a `.ui-checkbox` div. here are two different solutions. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/z3bv871b/ and http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/o1sfp3tb/

Comment: Not working, I think it may be because my form is injected

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/ncf4gz71/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried and it works fin with jQM.  Create a set of checkboxes:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="checkGroup">
    <legend>Vertical:</legend>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-v-2a" id="checkbox-v-2a">
    <label for="checkbox-v-2a">One</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-v-2b" id="checkbox-v-2b">
    <label for="checkbox-v-2b">Two</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-v-2c" id="checkbox-v-2c">
    <label for="checkbox-v-2c">Three</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-v-2d" id="checkbox-v-2d">
    <label for="checkbox-v-2d">Four</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-v-2e" id="checkbox-v-2e">
    <label for="checkbox-v-2e">Five</label>
</fieldset>
```

Then handle the change event.  Each time any checkbox changes state, count the number that are currently checked, and if it exceeds the maximum allowed, uncheck the one that just changed:

```
$('#checkGroup input[type="checkbox"]').on("change", function(){
    var numChecked = $('#checkGroup input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;

    if (numChecked > 3){
        $(this).prop("checked", "").checkboxradio("refresh");   
    }       
});
```

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/1ocu2bu7/)**

UPDATE:

OP is dynamically injecting the checkboxes, therefore, event delegation should be used to cath the change event:

```
$(document).on("change", '#ch input[type="checkbox"]', function(){
    var numChecked = $('#ch input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;       
    if (numChecked > 3){
        $(this).prop("checked", "").checkboxradio("refresh");   
    }       
});
```

Comment: @user3494068, can you update my jsFiddle in the answer to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @user3494068, because they are dynamic, you need to use event delegation: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/1ocu2bu7/2/, I have updated the answer.