# Limited number of answer checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, django, forms

I'm trying to create a form using html/javascript/django that allows the user to check one to three answers. Just like a choice with radio button, except that instead of beeing able to only check one, you can check up to three.
Any idea how I could do that?
Thanks!

Comment: use checkbox not radio

Comment: You could do it via Javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001844/how-to-limit-the-number-of-selected-checkboxes

Comment: This works perfectly, but the other answer also works and it allows me not to add JQuery. thank you very much for you time anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Bundle the checkboxen in some natively dom-searchable way (sharing a class, only input tags descendant from an ID'd tag, etc)
- Have all of them, onclick, call a function (passing this)
- If there's at least three other checked boxen, de-check this

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="limit3(this,'data-chkGroup');" class="data-chkGroup" />
```

JS:

```
function limit3(ele,classSet){
    var chks = document.getElementsByClassName(classSet);
    var disallow = 4;//+1 from allowed, so counting down results in 0 @ more than allowed
    for(var i = chks.length>>>0; i--;){
        if(chks[i].checked) disallow--;
        if(!disallow){
            ele.checked = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Advantage of this over those in that comment-linked 'similar question':
This uses native js, rather than including the bloat of jQ.

Comment: Well it works perfectly thank you very much :)

Comment: @Giltho No prob. Would appreciate you accepting this as the answer if you could.