# How to limit the number of checked checkbox in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, crowdflower

I know there're many answers to this, but none of them works for me.
My program is like:

```
 <cml:checkboxes label="Categories" name="categories">
  <cml:checkbox label="a" value="a" />
  <cml:checkbox label="b" value="b" />
  <cml:checkbox label="c" value="c" />
</cml:checkboxes>
```

Actually it's from CrowdFlower. Now what I want to do is to limit the maximal checked number to 2. I notice that many answers use **input** labels but that really doesn't work this way, because here the **checkbox** is embedded in a **checkboxes**. So anyone can help me with that? Thank you so much!

Comment: You might want to take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001844/how-to-limit-the-number-of-selected-checkboxes

Comment: If you feel I've wrongly closed this question please feel free to tell me, but first [edit] your question to address in what ways the existing – and there are several to choose from – failed to answer your question. In what way did they "*not work*," what did they do wrong? Or not do at all?