# How to limit checkbox selection in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database

So far I have been able to get data from MYSQL and display it as a checklist using PHP and HTML. Now I would like to limit the number of checkboxes that can be selected at a time. Javascript doesn't seem to be working with my PHP code.

EDIT: I've included my JScript below which is currently not workng. This JScript only works when I use it with manually created html checklists but not the one I have made below using MYSQL data. How can I fix my Javascript part so this works?

Here is my code:

```
<?php

    $username = "root";
    $password = "test";
    $hostname = "localhost";

    $dbname = "major_degrees";
    $str='';

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT degree_name FROM majors";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    $out = '';
    $cnt = 0;
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $cnt++;
            $out .= '<input id="cb_' .$cnt. '" class="someclass" type="checkbox" />' .$row['degree_name']. '<br/>';

        }
        echo $out;
    } 
    $conn->close();


?>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />

<script>
$out.on("click", ":checkbox", function(event){
        $(":checkbox:not(:checked)", this.form).prop("disabled", function(){
                return $(this.form).find(":checkbox:checked").length == 2;
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to limit the number of selected checkboxes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001844/how-to-limit-the-number-of-selected-checkboxes)

Comment: Where should the limit be enforced? On the client PHP has no power so javascript would be the choice.

Comment: You should also validate it on a server-side level (in PHP when processing these inputs). But using JS for limiting it on a client-side level, see the dupe I linked above.

Comment: @Qirel  I have made some edits in the code above. The JScript only seems to work with manually created check lists and not the one i have above from mysql. How can I make JS do the job with php above?

Comment: @Paolo I tried it with javascript (Edited above) and it still doesn't seem to work... any ideas on how this can be fixed?

Comment: Is there some form element (not shown in the snippet)? Open the browser's error console. What is the output?

Comment: [`JScript`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript) is not the same as `Javascript`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<script>
    $(".someclass").change(function() {
        var count = $(".someclass:checked").length; //get count of checked checkboxes

        if (count > 3) {
            alert("Only 3 options allowed..!");
            $(this).prop('checked', false); // turn this one off
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: it is still not working with my php code :( Would I have to include the JScript inside php? (I'm really new to these languages so please bare with me for the basic questions)

Comment: Does your page display as expected?  Have you looked in the console to see if any errors are occurring?

Comment: Yes, it displays the data from mysql line by line as checkboxes just as expected. But it lets me select any number of boxes when I only need 2 of them selected. It does not show any errors.

Comment: I tried it with your version of jQuery and it is working for me.  View the source of the HTML and ensure each checkbox has a class called 'someclass'. Then check more than 3 boxes, you should get the alert.

Comment: The code is working if i manually make the check boxes. The problem I'm having is when i run it without the html part, i.e just with php and js :( like in my code above I only have php and javascript.. there are no html tags