# Condition to unable user to check more than 3 boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, shopify, liquid

```
{% assign type_bonbon = "Sans sucre, Gélifié, Guimauve, Nougat, Acide, Doux" | split : ", " %}
<section class="page__content">
  {% capture contact_form %}
    <div class="contact">
        <div class="form__control">
            <label class = "form__label">{{ 'contact.form.type' | t }}</label>
            {% for type in type_bonbon %}
              <div class = "checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="contact[Bonbon {{type}}]" value="OUI">{{type}}
              </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
  {% endcapture %}
</section>
```

Hello guys,

I'm made a form where i make the user check the type of candy he wants.
However, i want the user to check maximum 3 values in the checkbox, the form should not let the user check more than 3 checkboxes.
I think i could get away by using Jquery and AJAX, however in shopify (liquid) i dont know how to implement this.
Thanks again for help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37503456/7158959   -   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001844/how-to-limit-the-number-of-selected-checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

Disable/enable the unchecked ones based on count of ones that are checked

```js
const $checks = $('.myChecks').on('change',()=>{
   const checkCount = $checks.filter(':checked').length;
   $checks.filter(':not(:checked)').prop('disabled', checkCount === 3);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="myChecks" type="checkbox"/>
<input class="myChecks" type="checkbox"/>
<input class="myChecks" type="checkbox"/>
<input class="myChecks" type="checkbox"/>
<input class="myChecks" type="checkbox"/>
<input class="myChecks" type="checkbox"/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much,
however i don't know if i can directly put this code in my liquid source file, or should i go by a js file

Comment: It does not work for me, idk what im doing wrong...