# How to set limit for radio button choice in a table?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

There is a table with 4 columns. Each columns has some radio buttons. User can select only one radio button from each column. As there is 4 columns in a table, so user can select 4 radio buttons from this table. But I want to give limit for the radio button selection. I want that user can select only 3 radio button from this table out of 4.If user want to select number 4, there will be an alert "You can not select more than three."

Is it possible to set limit here? How can I set this limit?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to limit the number of selected checkboxes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001844/how-to-limit-the-number-of-selected-checkboxes)

Answer (score 3):

```js
$("input[type='radio']").change(function(){
   var count = $("input[type='radio']:checked").length;
 if(count>3){
  $(this).prop('checked', false);
      alert("You cannot add more than 3");
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="radio" name="radioName1" value="1"> 1 <br>
<input type="radio" name="radioName1" value="2"> 2 <br>
<input type="radio" name="radioName1" value="3"> 3 <br>
<hr>
<input type="radio" name="radioName2" value="1"> 1 <br>
<input type="radio" name="radioName2" value="2"> 2 <br>
<input type="radio" name="radioName2" value="3"> 3 <br>
<hr>
<input type="radio" name="radioName3" value="1"> 1 <br>
<input type="radio" name="radioName3" value="2"> 2 <br>
<input type="radio" name="radioName3" value="3"> 3 <br>
<hr>
<input type="radio" name="radioName4" value="1"> 1 <br>
<input type="radio" name="radioName4" value="2"> 2 <br>
<input type="radio" name="radioName4" value="3"> 3 <br>
```

Comment: You doesn't need to use each to get count of radio. Only use `$('input[name=radioName]:checked').length` to do it.

Comment: This solves the checkbox question right to the point, but you cannot change your mind about the checkbox group selection you did once you have choosen any. As UI choice it'll need more JS than required with other form elements

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can't able to run this code. Can you share .html file with me?

Comment: Please do copy from the snippet or to see click **Run code snippet**,
Thanks @tanzilamohita.

Comment: I can run here but can't run from my pc. If you kindly share .html file it will be very helpful for me.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. One more question, if I want to use this depend on table name and input type radio, how can I write this? Should I write like this or anything else:

$("input[type='radio']" && "table[name='fr']").change(function()

Comment: Then Use table ID or class like  `$("#tableID input[type='radio']").change(function(){});` or `$(".tableClass input[type='radio']").change(function(){});` . Not only table you can use any parent element's id or class. @tanzilamohita

Comment: sorry for disturbing you a lot. Last ques:

I want to do this for a particular table. So how can I do this? there aretwo tables. table one id is "fri" and table two id is "sat". I want to do this only for table "fri" 

if(tableId = "fri"){
             do this
} else {
...........
}

How can I do this from this javascript? I am new in js. That's why facing too much problem.

Comment: Download again from  [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/189428416/stackoverflow/39890089.html) , i have added another table and reset button. @tanzilamohita

Answer (score 0):

You may store the selected radio name in an array and programmatically remove the oldest when the number of selected groups of radio buttons exceeds 3.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  var radioSelected = [];
  var numberOfSelected = null;

  $('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
    numberOfSelected = $('input[type=radio]:checked').length;
    var name = $(this)[0].name;
    if (radioSelected.indexOf(name) == -1) {
      radioSelected.push($(this)[0].name);
    }
    
    if(radioSelected.length > 3) {
      var removed = radioSelected.shift();
      $('input[name=' + removed + ']').prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
  
});
```

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 40px; 
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column">
  <div><input type="radio" name="one" value="i" /> i</div>
  <div><input type="radio" name="one" value="ii"/> ii</div>
  <div><input type="radio" name="one" value="iii"/> iii</div>
</div>

<div class="column">
  <div><input type="radio" name="two" /> A</div>
  <div><input type="radio" name="two" /> B</div>
  <div><input type="radio" name="two" /> C</div>
</div>

<div class="column">
  <div><input type="radio" name="three" /> 1</div>
  <div><input type="radio" name="three" /> 2</div>
  <div><input type="radio" name="three" /> 3</div>
</div>


<div class="column">
  <div><input type="radio" name="four" /> a</div>
  <div><input type="radio" name="four" /> b</div>
  <div><input type="radio" name="four" /> c</div>
</div>
```