# Product Add-On Checkbox Max 2 in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, checkbox, woocommerce

Using WooCommerce Product Add-Ons plugin I am trying to control the checkboxes to don't allow more than 2 checkboxes to be checked. This is not an option available with the plugin.

How do I do achieve this?

My actual code:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function ($) { 
        var $checkboxes = $('.addon-checkbox').click(function () {
            if ($checkboxes.filter(':checked').length > 2) {   
                $(this).prop('checked', false); return false;
            } 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: Sure thing! This actually worked, I needed to edit the class it was looking for.
<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $checkboxes = $('.addon-checkbox').click(function () {
        if ($checkboxes.filter(':checked').length > 2) {
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
            return false;
        }
    });
});</script>

Answer (score 2):

I tried this and it worked perfectly!

```
<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $checkboxes = $('.addon-checkbox').click(function () {
        if ($checkboxes.filter(':checked').length > 2) {
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
            return false;
        }
    });
});</script>
```

The class of .addon was not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the best or cleanest way, but you could use jQuery to [limit the checkbox selections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19001936/10317510). You'll need to change the selector to target whatever class is on the checkboxes.

```
(function($){
    var limit = 2;
    $('input.option-checkbox').on('change', function(event) {
        if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
            this.checked = false;
        }
    });
}(jQuery))
```

Save this script into a file then queue it up in your functions.php file.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-checkboxes', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/custom-checkboxes.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply Aaron.