# How to limit the number of selected checkboxes when click on div

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to checked the check box while click on the div.But I want to limit the number of check boxes which I can select. here is my html code.

```js
        $('.block').click(function () {
       $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked", 
    !$(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked"));
       $(this).css('border', '3px solid black');
    });



    $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
       if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 3) {
        $(this).prop('checked', false)
        alert("allowed only 3");
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-3">
          <div class="block">
              <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" value="1" />
              <img src="assets/img/products/1.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end pro block -->
        
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <div class="block">
            <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" value="2" />
              <img src="assets/img/products/1.jpg" alt="">
           </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end pro block -->
        
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <div class="block">
            <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" value="3" />
              <img src="assets/img/products/1.jpg" alt="">
           </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end pro block -->
        
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <div class="block">
            <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" value="4" />
              <img src="assets/img/products/1.jpg" alt=""> 
           </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end pro block -->
        
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <div class="block">
            <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" value="5" />
              <img src="assets/img/products/1.jpg" alt="">
               
           </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end pro block -->
        
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <div class="block">
            <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" value="6" />
              <img src="assets/img/products/1.jpg" alt="">    
           </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end pro block -->
        
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <div class="block">
           <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" value="7" />
              <img src="assets/img/products/1.jpg" alt="">           
           </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end pro block -->
        
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <div class="block">
           <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" value="8" />
              <img src="assets/img/products/1.jpg" alt="">
           </div>
        </div>
```

But it is not working. Can anyone help me.This answer also I take from below question.

[How to limit the number of selected checkboxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001844/how-to-limit-the-number-of-selected-checkboxes)

Comment: Can you explain what "not working" means?  Without a runnable example we don't know what it does.

Comment: @Archer I can select the check box when I click on the div. But can't limit number of check boxes which I can select.

Comment: @Lasa what does your console say?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to limit the number of selected checkboxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001844/how-to-limit-the-number-of-selected-checkboxes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

I do not myself understand why it happens this way and I will be grateful if someone can explain it to me but adding a click event to both checkbox and the div element, I noticed that that the click event was triggered on the checkbox first. In that function, I overrode the default behaviour on clicking a checkbox. This way, when the click event on the div element was triggered, the checkbox behaved as if it was not changed, and the code works as it was intended. Do notify me if there is still any unexpected behaviour.
Also, for the borders, we need the border when the checkbox is checked. So, I added a conditional block to set the border.

**Old**

The 'change' event is only triggered when you click on the checkbox, and not the entire div element.

If you want the alert even when you click somewhere on the body, do not use the change function. Instead, place your logic with the click function.

**Updated code**

```js
/*
$('.block').click(function () {
  let checkbox = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]');
  let val = checkbox.prop("checked");
  checkbox.prop("checked", !val);
  $(this).css('border', '3px solid black');
  if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 3) {
     checkbox.prop('checked', false)
     alert("allowed only 3");
  }
});
*/

$('.block').click(function(event) {

  let checkbox = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]');
  let val = checkbox.prop("checked");
  checkbox.prop("checked", !val);
  if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 3) {
    checkbox.prop('checked', false)
    return alert("allowed only 3");
  }
  if (checkbox.prop("checked")) {
    $(this).css('border', '1px solid #eee');
  } else {
    $(this).css('border', '');
  }

});


$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(event) {
  $(this).prop("checked", !$(this).prop("checked"));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="block">
      <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" value="1" />
      <img src="assets/img/products/1.jpg" alt="ALT">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end pro block -->

  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="block">
      <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" value="2" />
      <img src="assets/img/products/1.jpg" alt="ALT">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end pro block -->

  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="block">
      <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" value="3" />
      <img src="assets/img/products/1.jpg" alt="ALT">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end pro block -->

  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="block">
      <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" value="4" />
      <img src="assets/img/products/1.jpg" alt="ALT">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end pro block -->

  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="block">
      <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" value="5" />
      <img src="assets/img/products/1.jpg" alt="ALT">

    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end pro block -->

  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="block">
      <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" value="6" />
      <img src="assets/img/products/1.jpg" alt="ALT">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end pro block -->

  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="block">
      <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" value="7" />
      <img src="assets/img/products/1.jpg" alt="ALT">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end pro block -->

  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="block">
      <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" value="8" />
      <img src="assets/img/products/1.jpg" alt="ALT">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I fixed the CSS issue also by adding "$(this).css('border','' );"

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this. Your block highlighting and check box selection is not in sync. 
Have added the logic of limit in the parent block. Hope this helps!

```js
$('.block').click(function () {

   $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked", !$(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked"));
   
    if($(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked"))
   $(this).css('border', '3px solid black'); 
   else
   $(this).css('border', '');
   
       if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length >3) {
        $(this).children(0).prop('checked', false) ;               $(this).css('border','' );            
        alert("allowed only 3");    
       }
    
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-3">
          <div class="block">
              <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" value="1" />
              <img src="assets/img/products/1.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end pro block -->
        
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <div class="block">
            <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" value="2" />
              <img src="assets/img/products/1.jpg" alt="">
           </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end pro block -->
        
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <div class="block">
            <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" value="3" />
              <img src="assets/img/products/1.jpg" alt="">
           </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end pro block -->
        
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <div class="block">
            <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" value="4" />
              <img src="assets/img/products/1.jpg" alt=""> 
           </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end pro block -->
        
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <div class="block">
            <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" value="5" />
              <img src="assets/img/products/1.jpg" alt="">
               
           </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end pro block -->
        
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <div class="block">
            <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" value="6" />
              <img src="assets/img/products/1.jpg" alt="">    
           </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end pro block -->
        
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <div class="block">
           <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" value="7" />
              <img src="assets/img/products/1.jpg" alt="">           
           </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end pro block -->
        
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <div class="block">
           <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" value="8" />
              <img src="assets/img/products/1.jpg" alt="">
           </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: @Lasa-  Works fine in the snippet. Did you have a look at it?

Comment: No it's not works in the snippet also. This is the issue I have. I can select more than 3.

Comment: @Lasa Have a look at the updated code. Hope this helps!

Comment: This work if I click on the check box to select it. But here I want to click on the div to select the check box

Comment: Hey @Lasa, you havent specified that in your question. Please make sure you modify your question so that people who check this question later are not confused. Updated my answer. Please check !

Comment: I'll modify the question. Thanks for your answer. But here I just can select the check box. Can't deselect

Comment: @Lasa added that case as well

Answer (score 0):

I found an issue with checking checkboxes. I fixed and works fine. Just change this part of your code, this :

```
 $('.block').click(function () {
       $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked", 
    !$(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked"));
       $(this).css('border', '3px solid black');
    });
```

**With this:**

```
 $('.block').click(function () {
   $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked") 
   $(this).css('border', '3px solid black');
```

Hope this help:

**updates:**

> Remove your `change` method completely. Instead that part, edit the
>   first portion of your script like this:

```
   $('.block').click(function () {

       if($(this).find(".cb-element").prop("checked") == true)
       {
            $(this).find(".cb-element").prop('checked', false);
            $(this).removeAttr("style");
       }
       else if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length >= 3) 

       {
            //$(this).find(".cb-element").prop('checked', false);
            alert("allowed only 3");
        }
      else
      {
        console.log("checked new");
        $(this).prop('checked', true);

       $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked",
    !$(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked"));
       $(this).attr('style', 'border:3px solid black'); 
    }

});
```

Comment: This work if I click on the check box to select it. But here I want to click on the div to select the check box.

Comment: @Lasa, please check my updated answer. This should resolve your problem

Comment: now I can select only 3 , but now I can't deselect. If I try to deselect, same alert ("allowed only 3dd") pop up.

Comment: @Lasa, sorry my bad!
please check now

Comment: updated my question again!
demo:
https://codepen.io/code_fighter/pen/RzobVP