# Retrieve id when product is selected

Tags: php, mysqli

So, i'm developing a website that display products and compare them, in this case computers, this products are displayed in the index page and their info are from a database.  My main problem in the comparison system is how to send a id by selecting a product, how can i select the product to store the id.

This is the code from the main page where the products are

```
<?php
                        $get_product=get_product($con,4);
                        foreach($get_product as $list){
                        ?>
                        <!-- Start Single Category -->
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="category"> 
                            <div class="fr__hover__info compare_card<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
                                <ul class="product__action">
                                <label class="action action--compare-add"><input class="check-hidden" type="checkbox" /><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><i class="fa fa-check"></i><span class="action__text action__text--invisible">Comparar</span></label>
                                  
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                                <div class="ht__cat__thumb">
                                    <a href="product.php?id=<?php echo $list['id']?>">
                                        <img src="<?php echo PRODUCT_IMAGE_SITE_PATH.$list['image']?>" alt="product images">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="fr__product__inner ">
                                    <h4><a href="product.php?id=<?php echo $list['id']?>"><?php echo $list['name']?></a></h4>
                                    <ul class="fr__pro__prize">
                                        <li><?php echo $list['price'], '€'?></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
<label class="action action--compare-add"><input class="check-hidden" type="checkbox" /><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><i class="fa fa-check"></i><span class="action__text action__text--invisible">Comparar</span></label>
```

More specifically:

```
<input class="check-hidden" type="checkbox" />
```

For each product displayed (that a user may select for comparison), you need to add a name attribute indicating it may send an array of values (multiple product IDs).

```
<input class="check-hidden" type="checkbox" name='compareIds[]' value='<?php echo $list['id']?>'/>
```

The selected answer here explains how to receive the POST data and use it once you get to the comparison part of your code. The above just makes sure that you receive the IDs of all products selected.

If you want to limit the number of products to two (or some other limit), a Javascript snippet can achieve it. See solution here:
[How to limit the number of selected checkboxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001844/how-to-limit-the-number-of-selected-checkboxes)