# if i have five checkboxes, how do i limit a user to just three selections

Tags: html

CONFECTIONARIES

Cake Making
  
   chin chin making
  
   Dough Nut making
  
   Pea Nut making
  
   Buns making
  
   Custard making

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001844/how-to-limit-the-number-of-selected-checkboxes

Answer (score -1):

you can do this with jQuery

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function (e) {
if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 3) {
    $(this).prop('checked', false);
    alert("allowed only 3");
}
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vVxM2/)

Or in vanilla js https://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/checkbox-limit.php