# Checkboxes in HTML

Tags: html, input, attributes

What input attribute do I use to make  sure the user does not select everything in a list of html checkboxes? For example, I have created five checkboxes, but I want users to only select a maximum of three. I don't want to use radio buttons in this case. Please keep solutions to only HTML, not javascript.

Thanks. First newbie question here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to limit the number of selected checkboxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001844/how-to-limit-the-number-of-selected-checkboxes)

Comment: No it doesn't, the answers in that thread are about JavaScript.

Comment: You need to use JavaScript to achieve this client-side.

Comment: Thank you. I will get there soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML does not have any validation feature that makes that kind of check possible.

You *need* to use JavaScript to achieve this client-side.

You can use the [`setCustomValidity` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLObjectElement/setCustomValidity) with your custom rules to generate an error message that uses the same style as the native HTML validation messages.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I didn't know that. However, your answer helped me learn about HTMLObjectElement. I guess I have a long way to go. Is it a part of the things I must learn in HTML?